# Tracker-enabled-dbcontext. Auditlog and AuditLogDetails tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, tracker-enabled-dbcontext

I am trying to implement Tracker-enabled-dbcontext in my program. Using VS2015 i added ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project, then i installed Tracker-enabled-dbcontext from NuGet. I inherited TrackerContext and applied [TrackChanges] attribute, but i cant find the "Auditlog" tables.
I think i did everything according to [this instruction](https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext/wiki).

Can anyone point me into the right direction and tell me how to implement this?

Comment: are you using code-first? it seems model/database-first isn't supported https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext/issues/31

Comment: I was not using code-first. But i changed my approach and now everything is fine. Thanks!